# Nginx Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx

My entire website in ubuntu is down.When I check the status.I got:

```
Aug 30 21:39:44 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01 nginx[23017]: **nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive invalid value in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2**
Aug 30 21:39:44 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01 nginx[23017]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Aug 30 21:39:44 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 30 21:39:44 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01 systemd[1]: **Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.**
```

This is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes autoi;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: The error message is clear in this case: `"worker_processes" directive invalid value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

worker_processes should be "auto;" You wrote autoi; with "i"